# Unsure of how to call my method to be run from main() with a switch statement

Tags: java

**Problem:** I'm relatively new to Java, and I'm trying to understand how to call a class (or are classes methods?) to the main class to be executed. Also will my System.out message be printed from where it is? I was trying to place it inside the doubleDice class, but was getting errors.

```
package dicerolling;
public class DiceRolling {

public static void main(String[] args) {

DoubleDice.doubleRoll();

    }

}
```

**What I hope to get:** I'm hoping to get an output from the prompt that rolls the dice, and executes through the switch as well **from a separate class**.

**What I'm getting now:** Everything runs fine, but I don't know how to work with methods outside of the main.

**EDIT:**

```
public class DoubleDice {

public static void doubleRoll() {

    int maxNum = 6;
    int randomValue = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * maxNum);
    int randomValue2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * maxNum);
    int die1 = (randomValue);
    int die2 = (randomValue2);
    int sum = die1 + die2;

    System.out.println(
            "With a roll of the dice: " + die1
            + " + " + die2 + " = " + sum);

    switch (sum) {
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Snake Eyes!");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Craps!");
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("Box Cars!");
            break;

    }
  }
}
```

**What I'm getting now:** I'm trying to call the DoubleDice class from a different file, but before I can do that; My system.out and switch statement are now showing errors.

EDIT: Solved!

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Why do you have a class *inside* your `main` method?

Comment: I'm being nice when I say, perhaps some tutorials are in order? This is way off. You need to either use static classes or instantiate the class as an object. Also classes don't go inside methods.

Comment: @Thomas Oh, I had initially setup the integers to run, and figured I could just wrap it in a class. How would I clean this up?

Comment: @JBen Honestly, unless you need a class, just make it a method. Classes are for categorizing stuff but for this...unsure if it's really needed. See the provided answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main()` method does not contain any operators. What it contains is a definition of a [local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) named `doubleDice`.

As it contains no operators, nothing happens when `main()` is run.

You could, for example, move that local class to a top level (that is, create a file named `doubleDice.java` containing that class definition inside it), and then instantiate it and call its method inside your `main()`:

```
new doubleDice().combination();
```

One more thing: according to standard Java naming convention, class names are started with a capital letter, so `DoubleDice` is preferred to `doubleDice` as class name.

Comment: I've created a a top level, but I'm getting an identifier error for my System.out and switch now.  I'm going to edit my post to clarify.